# How do I pass an argument to this solidity function from react?

Tags: solidity, react

I'm trying to use a form to submit the data, but every time I try to run the code it throws an error.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
  uint storedData;

  function set(uint256 x) public {
    storedData = x;
  }

  function get() public view returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your Javascript code look like currently? But this is not about React, this is more of a JavaScript/web3 question. And what web3 library are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.